# If $f$ is $L^p$ then $f\circ \phi$ is $L^p$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let (X, B, µ) be a measure space and M ∈ (0, ∞).
Suppose that $\phi : X \to X$ is a map satisfying that
$$\phi^{-1}(A) \in B$$ and $$\mu(\phi^{-1}(A)) \leq M\mu(A)$$ for all $A \in B$
Then I need to show that if f is $L^p$, then $f\circ \phi$ is in $L^p$ too for $p$ greater than or equal to 1. I already showed that $$\int_X f \circ\phi d\mu \leq M\int_X f d\mu$$ but I don't see how to conclude, I tried to split the integral into one part where $f\circ\phi \leq 1$ and the other where $f\circ\phi \geq 1$ but I'm at a dead end. Thank you. (Oh and I try not to use the pull-back measure since I haven't seen it in my lectures)

Comment: What is $M \phi (A)$? A real number?

Comment: @Snoop Sorry it was a $\mu$ instead of $\phi$

Comment: What's wrong with applying the "$L^1$" result you have to $F=|f|^p$ for $f\in L^p$?